# python function parameter screwing up

Tags: python, function, parameters

so I have

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if a == 0:
            return b
    while b != 0:
            if a > b:
                    a = a - b
            else:
                    b = b - a
    return a
```

but then when I call gcd(1,2) from the console, the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    G.gcd(1,2)
TypeError: gcd() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

comes up....

which makes no sense  at all since I only gave 2 arguments...

what did I do wrong?

allright so I deleted everything else and this is the only thing in my class:

```
import random
import math

class RSA:
    def gcd(a,b):
        if a == 0:
            return b
        while b != 0:
            if a > b:
                a = a - b
            else:
                b = b - a
        return a
```

and the problem still persists

Comment: You have more that you aren't showing.

Comment: I don't really know what version you're using but for python 2.6 >= you can use `from fractions import gcd` just to not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling the function as a method. Add "self" as the first argument and it'll work.

Comment: SpliFF had the same answer and 14 seconds before I did. But I got the accept. I guess it's my lucky day.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to add "self" just call the method unbound. Then it's like function. It would be `RSA.gcd()` instead of `G.gcd()`.

Answer (score 5):

You have not posted all of your code.  The code you didn't post looks like this:

```
class SomeClass:

    def gcd(a,b):
        if a == 0:
                return b
        while b != 0:
                if a > b:
                        a = a - b
                else:
                        b = b - a
        return a 

G = SomeClass()
G.gcd(1,2)
```

In python, when you define a class member function, the class instance is automatically passed to the function.  Change your code to look like this:

```
class SomeClass:

    def gcd(a,b):
        if a == 0:
                return b
        while b != 0:
                if a > b:
                        a = a - b
                else:
                        b = b - a
        return a 

G = SomeClass()
G.gcd(1,2)
```

or better yet

```
def gcd( a,b):
    if a == 0:
            return b
    while b != 0:
            if a > b:
                    a = a - b
            else:
                    b = b - a
    return a 

gcd(1,2)
```

and all will be well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator like this:

```
...
class RSA:    

    @staticmethod
    def gcd(a,b):
        ...
```

Comment: Instance methods that never use `self` in the body are a code smell. This should either be a static method, or defined outside the class somewhere as a function

Answer (score 2):

if gcd is a method inside the class then you should define it as follows:

def gcd(self, a, b): etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect (since the error is in code you haven't provided) that gcd is actually a method and you are calling it as obj.gcd(a,b). This is translated as gcd(self, a, b) = 3 arguments. you need to define the function with the self argument.

Answer (score 1):

There's already an accepted answer that solves the problem, but I'd like to point out, that (IMHO) a more idiomatic solution in Python would be to move the `gcd` method outside the class to a plain function in the module.

I mean, it's a general purpose function. There's no reason in Python to encapsulate it in a class.

Answer (score 0):

I just threw that code into Python (in interpreter mode) and it seems to work just fine. Are you sure gcd isn't being redefined anywhere? Python will allow you to redefine functions without warning, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The code as you provide it, works fine in an interpreter. If you're calling gcd() as a method, you need to add "self" as first argument.

```
    def gcd(self, a, b):
        //...
```